# Increasing the frequency of modeline redisplay

Tags: mode-line, display

**Q:** Is there a way to (temporarily) increase the rate at which the mode line is redisplayed?

I was trying to write a package that adds a spinner to the mode line
(to indicate ongoing operations), but I hit a bit of a wall. If the
user is not interacting (not typing, or moving, or something), then
the mode-line might stop updating for up to a minute. If that's the
case then the spinner won't spin.

I started writing a solution with timers (that would periodically
call `redisplay`), but that seems like a lot of work for something so
simple.

Comment: I would probably do the same thing, except link the timer to `force-mode-line-update`; or, perhaps have the spinner function keep triggering `force-mode-line-update` if the spinner is going through something like a `dolist` or `while` loop -- each loop is a `force-mode-line-udpate`.  Also, consider using a regular timer that is not necessarily an idle timer.

Comment: @lawlist thanks for the pointer to force-mode-line-update . I don't know why I said idle-timer, I meant timer.

Comment: @lawlist: Looks like a complete answer and not a comment.

Comment: @Malabarba I believe you followed up on this elsewhere, and even implemented a package which needs this to work correctly. Could you please share your findings.

Comment: @tarsius Oh yes! I'd forgotten about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of the solution I came up (had to use
timers after all). For the complete solution, see
[spinner.el](https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/spinner.el).

```
(let ((timer (run-at-time t 0.2 #'ignore)))
  (timer-set-function
   timer (lambda ()
           (if still-ongoing
               (force-mode-line-update)
             (ignore-errors (cancel-timer timer))))))
```

This creates a timer that updates the mode-line 5 times per second.
When the variable `still-ongoing` gets set to `nil`, the time cancels
itself.

Comment: Nice to see I am not the only one who indents like this, when given the opportunity :-)